# Polymer 2.0 Custom Event Handling

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

So I want to dispatch custom event from the child element.

```js
<dom-module id="layout-dashboard">
<template>
    <style></style>

</template>
    <script>
        class LayoutDashboard extends Polymer.Element {
        connectedCallback() {
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('kick-start', {detail : {}, bubble: true, composed : true}))
        }
    }
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

And then handle the event from the parent.

```js
<dom-module id="layout-parent">
    <template>
        <style></style>
        <layout-dashboard on-kick-start="handleKick"></layout-dashboard>
    </template>
    <script>
        class LayoutParent extends Polymer.Element {
            handleKick(){
                console.log("test");
            }
        }
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Any idea why `handleKick()` is not executed?

Answer (score 6):

Your code structure for defining `custom-element` is wrong. Please read [custom element concepts](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements) and [quick tour](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/quick-tour) of polymer.

The basic structure is like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="...">
<dom-module id='my-element'>
    <template>
        <style></style>
    </template>
    <script>
       class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
          static get is() {
            return "my-element";
          }

        }
        customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

The mistakes you have done:

1. `<script></script>` and then you wrote your scripts.
2. `<script></script>` is inside `<template>` that should be outside `<template>`and inside `<dom-module>`.
3. For the custom element lifecycle you need call the superclass method. This is required so Polymer can hook into the element's lifecycle. i.e:

   `connectedCallback() {
     super.connectedCallback();
     // …
    }`
4. You need to register the new element with the browser

   `customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);`

I have made a plnkr demo to solve the issue. Please have a look at : http://plnkr.co/edit/p5qvt4cIEJBobrmY8QDg?p=preview .

Comment: The detail object has to be accessed via the event ?

Comment: Yes. You have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Dashes in the event name are fine.  Start by fully defining and registering your elements.

Example from the Polymer docs [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/first-element/step-2).  Note the is() getter and the customElements.define at the end which registers your element.

```
<script>
  class IconToggle extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() {
      return "icon-toggle";
    }
    constructor() {
      super();
    }
  }
  customElements.define(IconToggle.is, IconToggle);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not specified in the Polymer doc, but I suppose it's because the event name contains a dash. If you want to handle this event, I suggest you to add a listener once connect.

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to the LayoutParent ready function:

```
        ready() {
            super.ready();
            window.addEventListener('kick-start', (e) => this.handleKick(e));
        }
```

nb; for Polymer 2.0 (as described in @Ofisora's post)

Comment: The above code is already in `Polymer 2.0` and there is no need to add `eventlistener` as the child element is dispatching the event when it is added to the document.i.e.`connectedCallback`.